# Можно ли написать массив байтов вручную, но не писать к каждому числу (byte)?

Tags: java, конвертация, byte

Пример

```
byte[] packet = new byte[] {0xFE, 0x19, 0xAE, ...}
```

Приходится к каждму числу делать приставку {(byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x19, (byte) 0xAE, ... }

можно сделать конвертер int в байт, но меня такой вариант смущает, так как кол-во памяти в разы увеличивается, да и работа лишняя на CPU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как пишет [документация](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), тип `byte` может содержать значения в пределах от `-128` до `127`. Значения, которые выходят за этот диапазон, нужно приводить к типу явно. Из этого следует:

```
byte[] packet = new byte[] { (byte) 0xFE, 0x19, (byte) 0xAE, ... };
```

Всегда, когда идет речь о потере точности или усечении значения, нужно явно приводить тип.